# Convergence in Distribution in Order Statistics

Tags: convergence, joint-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be iid from Exp$(\theta)$ with density function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$.

(a) Find the limiting distribution of $M_n = Y_1 - \theta\ln(n)$ and $T_n = nY_n$, where $Y_1$ and $Y_n$ represent the first and last order statistics (among $n$ observations) respectively.

**Answer**: I have obtained the CDF of X to be:
$$F_x(x) = 1 - e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

the CDF of $Y_1$ to be:
$$F_{Y_1} = 1 = e^{-\frac{xn}{\theta}}$$

the CDF of $M_n$ to be:
$$F_{M_n}(x) = \left[1 - \frac{1}{n}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}\right]^n$$

with limiting distribution
$$e^{-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}$$

the CDF of $T_n$ to be:
$$F_{T_n}(x) = 1 - e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

which is also the limiting distribution.

(b) Show that $M_n$ and $T_n$ are asymptotically independent.

**Answer**: I've tried finding the joint PDF for ordered statistics by using the equation
$$g_{ij}(y_i, y_j) = \frac{n!}{(i - 1)!(j - i - 1)!(n - j)!}[F(y_i)]^{i - 1}[F(y_j) - F(y_i)]^{j - i - 1}[1 - F(y_j)]^{n - j}f(y_i)f(y_j)$$

however, it is a mess based on my CDFs. Any suggestions on a different approach?

Comment: It is curious that another account asked exactly the same question 7 hours ago at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489643.  There I provided advice that should serve you well: compute the joint distribution of $(M_n,T_n).$

Comment: Not sure how to respond to that.

Comment: You could try it and show us what progress you make.

Comment: Note that $Y_n$ is stochastically increasing so $nY_n$ is a.s. going to infinity.

Comment: I asked it once yesterday thank you. Apparently it was not to certain standards, so I reworded and include more of my solution.

Comment: I think you inverted min and max in the question. Looking at $nX_{(1)}=nY_1$ makes sense. And a full answer for $X_{(n)}-\theta\log(n)$ is given on [maths.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2735316/14893).

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3847941/321264.